# SmallDateTime Min and Max Values in C#

Tags: c#, sql

In C# there's a `SqlDateTime.MinValue` and `SqlDateTime.MaxValue`, but I can't find one for the `SmallDateTime` datatype from SQL Server.

```
var smallDateTimeMin = DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
var smallDateTimeMax = DateTime(2079, 6, 6);
```

Is there one or do I need to implement this myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `smalldatetime` equivalent in `System.Data.SqlTypes`.  Nor is there an equivalent for the new `datetime2` type.  So I wouldn't expect min-max constants for those types in the .NET framework.

But the types are well documented on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types):

> Date and time data from January 1,
>   1753 through December 31, 9999, to an
>   accuracy of one three-hundredth of a
>   second (equivalent to 3.33
>   milliseconds or 0.00333 seconds).
>   Values are rounded to increments of
>   .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown
>   in the table.

So you can easily define your own min-max constants.

Comment: `smalldatetime` only works through June 6th, 2079, according to the documentation you've linked.

Answer (score 19):

Why not use an extension method?

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime SmallDateTimeMinValue(this DateTime sqlDateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
    }
    public static DateTime SmallDateTimeMaxValue(this DateTime sqlDateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(2079, 06, 06, 23, 59, 00);
    }

}


DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Minvalue is {0} ", date.SmallDateTimeMinValue().ToShortDateString());
```

Admittedly, it'd be nice for extension properties, but those don't exist yet.

Answer (score 5):

For my purposes I used a simple static helper class:

```
public static class SqlSmallDateTime
{
    public static readonly SqlDateTime MinValue = 
        new SqlDateTime(new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00));

    public static readonly SqlDateTime MaxValue = 
        new SqlDateTime(new DateTime(2079, 06, 06, 23, 59, 00));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `SQLDateTime` [maps to both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx) `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, I guess you'll have to do that manually.

Answer (score 2):

Min value 1900-01-01 00:00:00

Max value 2079-06-06 23:59:00

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use your own constants. It would seem that the `System.Data.SqlTypes` namespace is incomplete without `SqlSmallDateTime`, but that's actually not the case. The purpose of that namespace is to provide classes that prevent type conversion errors.

> The System.Data.SqlTypes namespace provides classes for native data types within SQL Server 2005. These classes provide a safer, faster alternative to the data types provided by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR). Using the classes in this namespace helps prevent type conversion errors caused by loss of precision. Because other data types are converted to and from SqlTypes behind the scenes, explicitly creating and using objects within this namespace also yields faster code.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx)

Because `SqlDateTime` is sufficient for that purpose, no `SqlSmallDateTime` is provided.